# Nodejs, Express GET POST params

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm new to Node/Express..  I see GET params can be captured like so:

```
app.get('/log/:name', api.logfunc);
```

POST like so:

`app.post('/log', ...`  (form variables available in req.body.)

I'm aware of app.all, but is there a single way I can get all the variables for GET and POST when using app.all?  (I'm too used to $_REQUEST in php!:)

thx,

Comment: `JSON.stringify(req.query)` for `get` and `JSON.stringify(req.body)` for `post` assuming you `app.use(express.bodyParser())`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're dealing with three different methods of parameter-passing:

1) Path parameters, which express's router captures in `req.param` when you use colon-prefixed components or regex captures in your route. These can be present in both GET and POST requests.

2) URL query-string parameters, which will be captured in `req.query` if you use the `express.query` middleware. These can also be present in both GET and POST requests.

3) Body parameters, which will be captured in `req.body` if you use the `express.bodyParser` middleware. These will only be present in POST requests that have a `Content-Type` of "x-www-form-urlencoded".

So what you need to do is to merge all three objects (if they exist) into one. There are no native `Object` methods for doing this, but there are lots of popular workarounds. For example, the [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org) library defines an `extend` function, which would allow you to write

```
req.params=_.extend(req.params || {}, req.query || {}, req.body || {}).
```

If you don't want to use a library and want to roll your own way of extending objects, take a look at [this blog post](http://onemoredigit.com/post/1527191998/extending-objects-in-node-js).

Comment: I believe `req.param()` does exactly that - http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.param

Answer (score 0):

Personnaly, i merge `req.params`, `req.body`, `req.query` in one single object `req.props` with `Object.assign()`

**in ES6:**

You just need to write this in your route:

```
   app.all('/myroute/:myparam', (req, res, next) => {
        // merge all req data in one
        req.props = Object.assign(req.query, req.params, req.body);
        // optional :
        // delete req.query;
        // delete req.params;
        // delete req.body;
    });
```

**In ES5:**

```
    app.all('/myroute/:myparam', function(req, res, next){
        // merge all req data in one
        req.props = {};
        if(req.query)  for (var attrname in req.query)  { req.props[attrname] = req.query[attrname]; }
        if(req.params) for (var attrname in req.params) { req.props[attrname] = req.params[attrname]; }
        if(req.body)   for (var attrname in req.body)   { req.props[attrname] = req.body[attrname]; }
        // optional :
        // delete req.query;
        // delete req.params;
        // delete req.body;
    });
```

Now, you can access easily to your GET, POST, PUT params with `req.props` in all your routes, be careful about similars name if you decide to delete the old req.

Also, you can do a middleware/functions to make it more useful yet.

More about `Object.assign()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/assign